# separating button logic on javascript

Tags: javascript, haml

The problem I am having is that I cannot distinguish between these two buttons. One button affects the other. Here is the code:

```
%input.radio-button{:name => "donor_claim_phase-c#{index}", :type => "radio", :id => "donor_claim_phase-c#{index}" }
%input.radio-button{:name => "global_start_phase-c#{index}", :type => "radio", :id => "global_start_phase-c#{index}" }
```

and the Javascript I have is this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(e){
    var selectedRadioName = $(this).attr('name');
    disableNonSelectedRadioButtons(selectedRadioName);
});
```

The problem is, this function disables both because both are of type="radio". Is there some other way I can distinguish between the two? Is there some way I can make two functions where I give a type=radio and some other factor to distinguish them?

```
function disableNonSelectedRadioButtons(selectedRadioButton) {
    $('#payer-contract-global-table .clone-target').each(function (i)  {
        var radioName = 'donor_claim_phase' + '-c' + i;
        if (selectedRadioButton == radioName) {
            $('#' + radioName).prop("checked", true);
            $('#' + radioName).prop("value", true);
            $('#payer_contract_donor_claim_phase').prop("value", (i+1));
        }
        else {
            $('#' + radioName).prop("checked", false);
            $('#' + radioName).prop("value", false);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Added the function disableNonSelectedRadioButtons. The first is HAML.

Comment: Does this code not work? I don't see anything very wrong, other than that `$('#' + radioName).prop("value", true);` should probably be `$('#' + radioName).val('true')`.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons are like car radios: press one and the others pop out. If you want multiple choices use  **n** individual buttons.